# html input field "value id" combination

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to understand what exactly the combination

```
... value id= ...
```

in

```
<input type="text" name="session_key" value id="session-key-login">
```

does. Note, that the value is immediately followed by id.

My problem is whenever such a combination occurs in an input field (for example in Facebook login page "email or phone" field (only) and everywhere in the LinkedIn login page), the

```
 document.getElementById(..).focus()
```

method fails. I am sure the "value id" combination does something non-trivial, since Facebook uses it only for one field, while all other fields come without that empty value field preceeding id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two totally different attributes.  Note that attributes are separated by spaces, so even when specified with no `=` afterwards, as in your example, it's a distinct attribute, and not combined with the following one.

- `value` defines the value of the input (the value that will be prefilled when the page is rendered).  If left empty (as in your example), it does nothing.  If you did, say, `value="hi"`, however, the text box would be prefilled with "hi"
- `id` specifies the unique identifying name of the input.  It is used to access the element in the DOM, using JavaScript, e.g. `document.getElementById('session-key-login')`

Comment: I agree. But why not just `... id=...` or `.. value=" " id =...`

More importantly, why the focus method fails only for such fields?

Comment: Appended the answer to that in my answer.

Comment: I am doing exactly that. I don't know if it is specific with my code (somewhere else), but the focus would work with  `document.getElementById('session-key-login')` if there is no `value` immediately before `id`

Comment: It should work either way.  Try `value=""` and see if that fixes the problem.  You may also be duplicating the ID on your page, which is a different problem.  You can only use an ID once per page.  It must be unique.

Comment: actually I am running a javascript to focus on an external page, for e.g. facebook. So, I can't alter the input field, except via js. When I ask to focus on the password (or any other field except 'email/phone' for that matter) the focusing does work well. The only difference I could see in these fields on the page is that "value id" combination :(

Comment: The value attribute isn't your issue.  It's more likely a sandbox issue.  I suggest you create another question with a broader question related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my focus() problem.

What I found was on a page, invoking focus() once focuses on the required element. However, a second invocation on the same element fails, unless one make the page lose the previous focus explicitly, for e.g. by invoking the blur() method on the same element.

I might be wrong, but my guess is that Facebook focuses on the "email" field implicitly/automatically on load and thus my second focus does not do anything. Though it works on other fields.

So, explanation by Steven Moseley holds tight :)

Thanks,
Nikhil